# SVG animated gradient color

Tags: svg

I have the following SVG code:

```html
<svg height="130" width="500">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="logo-gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#054f16">
        <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#054f16; #91bc9c" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
      </stop>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#01FF89">
        <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#91bc9c; #054f16" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
      </stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <ellipse cx="100" cy="70" rx="85" ry="55" fill="url(#logo-gradient)" />
  <text fill="#ffffff" font-size="45" font-family="Verdana" x="50" y="86">SVG</text>
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```

I am looking to animate the gradient to keep smoothly flowing in the SVG container, behind the text. As you can see from [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TheRealPapa/kf4qbjxw/), it is jumpy. How do I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the animation to cycle around/back to the starting point, just add an extra value to each `values` attribute.  The value should be the starting colour.

```html
<svg height="130" width="500">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="logo-gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#054f16">
        <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#054f16; #91bc9c; #054f16" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
      </stop>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#01FF89">
        <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#91bc9c; #054f16; #91bc9c" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
      </stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <ellipse cx="100" cy="70" rx="85" ry="55" fill="url(#logo-gradient)" />
  <text fill="#ffffff" font-size="45" font-family="Verdana" x="50" y="86">SVG</text>
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```